# UIImage not clipped by clipping path

Tags: ios, uiimage, drawrect, rounded-corners

I have a UIView subclass which contains a UIImageView. I want the image to appear circular, so I did this:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSaveGState(ctx);
    CGPathRef clippath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:rect cornerRadius:17].CGPath;
    CGContextAddPath(ctx, clippath);
    CGContextClip(ctx);
    [self.imageView.image drawInRect:rect];
    CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);
}
```

However, the images are not circular, they are regular rectangles. What's the issue?

Comment: is your UIImageView a subview of your UIView?  If so it will be shown over the drawRect function drawing, and therefore you are seeing the UIImageView not your UIView with custom drawing.

Comment: My UIImageView is actually an AsyncImageView subclass of UIImageView. My UIView has a xib, and in that xib the AsyncImageView is added and connected to an outlet called imageView. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes.  If your imageView is on top of your UIView (as a subview) then you will never see the drawing.  You have a couple options, I'll post in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ac couple options you have are either to breate a cornerRadius on your UIImageView so that it appears circular or remove the UIImageView from your UIView's subviews.

In the first case you don't need to have the custom drawing since the circle picture that you want will be drawn in the UIImageView with cornerRadius (and clipsToBounds enabled).

In the second you don't need a UIImageView at all, just a UIImage.  The UIImageView is just a way to display a UIImage on screen, and if that's taken care of in the custom drawing of your view then you don't need the UIImageView.

Given these options I believe the UIImageView with cornerRadius would be the most efficient.  Custom drawing takes a bit of processor time that the UIImageView would take care of for you.

Comment: First of all, I was looking on SO the whole day and everyone seemed to suggest that clipping paths were much faster than rounded corners. That's what I've been trying to avoid. Second, I need to use the UIImageView, because as I told you, it's not actually a UIImageView but an AsyncImageView, so I need it's functionality. Couldn't I do it somehow with clipsToBounds?

Comment: You may be misunderstanding what he's suggesting.  If you have something like `[self addSubview:self.imageView]` somewhere in your code, or if that view is a subview in your xib, then the unclipped image will draw over the clipped image that you're creating in `drawRect`.